# Show Jersey trace in Mule

Tags: configuration, jersey, mule

Jersey has a [tracing feature](http://blogs.oracle.com/sandoz/entry/tracing_in_jersey) that looks to be helpful.  However the instructions on enabling it assume that I have a web.xml file to put the configuration in.  My mule instance is standalone and I have no web.xml file.  How do I enable the Jersey tracing?

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to find the correct way using configuration files, but for debugging purposes this worked.  I downloaded the source and modified the calls that were checking for tracing, compiled with Maven and placed the jars in my Maven repository.